# how to override $block->content in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Now, if i want to override the $block->content which is generated by the Book module... how can I  override it and customize the title list? thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the preprocess_block function

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['block'])) {
      print_r($vars);
    }
  }
```

And dig into those results.

About the content, is this is a module generated block, I hope that `$content` is renderer using a `theme()` function, so you just need to alter it.

Comment: the block is generated by the book module. how should i do? thank you

Comment: I'd recommend using the Devel module and using the dpm() function it provides to get easier to read debug output.

Answer (score 2):

The $vars argument will have all the information about the blocks being themed. In your case you want the module to be "book".

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_block(&$vars) {    
    if (isset($vars['block'])) {
      if($vars['block']->module == 'book') {
        $vars['block']->content = "My new content";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Good one PPC-code, I knew about phptemplate_preprocess_node, but  phptemplate_preprocess_block looks interesting. Does all the entities in drupalhave preprocess functions?

Comment: They only apply to theming hooks implemented as templates (plain theme functions don't get preprocessors). See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383865/how-do-i-use-theme-preprocessor-functions-for-my-own-templates

Comment: PPC-Coder,i'm sorry, i out you code in my theme's template.php.but it can't work.

Comment: What's not working? I just added a Book navigation block to my page and was able to change it's content to "My New Content".

Comment: i have installed the DHTML Menu,and make it effect to the book navigation block.

Comment: if i disabled the DHTML Menu,it can output the "My New Content". but i want to use the DHTML Menu and can output the "My New Content". how should i do, thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with DHTML Menu but if it is also affecting the Block output and you want to keep it you can still do some string manipulation to modify ti however you want. Like this (or something more elaborate): $vars['block']->content = "My new content" . $vars['block']->content;

Answer (score 2):

you can use a preprocess_block function

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_block(&$vars)
{
     if(isset($vars['block']))
     {
          //i have override a footer_block 
          if($vars['block']->region == 'footer_block')
          {
              $vars['content] = "Please Enter Some data";
          }
     }
}
```