# Where do I see Drupal source code

Tags: drupal-6, xampp, drupal-views

I am a newbie to Drupal site development. My basic question is where do I see the files for eg: HomePage.PHP or whatever.

I saved a block in Drupal but I don't find the same under drupal folder. So what I am missing?

Please help me.

FYI: I am using Drupal 6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blocks are stored in the MySQL Database, you won't see it at all in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move those pages to another server just move the db.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a index.php, it's "pushed" out by drupal. However, you should be able to edit the theme(page format). Under ./sites/all/themes/THEMENAME/page.tpl.php.

Also, you should be using Drupal 7.x [here](http://drupal.org/project/drupal).

Last, a good place to look at the structure of a Drupal Page [here](http://drupal.org/node/171194).

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi Nathan,thx for ur post. I have actually created few pages such as home page,courses page,about me page using drupal.I am just wondering where to access all this code.I dont find it in drupal folder in my theme folder.I need to access this as I need to dump this website in another server.Please help me asap.

Comment: FYI. I recently downloaded drupal

Comment: Drupal system is a little different from you basic index system. You won't really be able to just see you're page, or block, in full HTML. What the Drupal system does is look at your theme, then; base on the layout of the theme, outputs the HTML page. Now if you want to edit, lets say, a block; you would have to use a theme preprocessor. [Here how to use theme preprocessor has been explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383865/how-do-i-use-theme-preprocessor-functions-for-my-own-templates)

Comment: Herp a Derp... You want to transfer your Drupal site to a new server... [You should look at this module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) it's for backing up your site and transferring it. Then just move your theme into the ./sites/all/themes. Now you have your site on a new server. Also, just make sure you have other modules, from your old server, installed on the new server before transferring all your data. Haha, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created all these pages as node from admin side, So all your pages will be saved into the database.
You can check it in node table of your database.
Finally if you want to move all these pages to the server, then just move the Database to the server.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: firstly appreciate ur help. will i not be able to c in my themes folder.yes i see my pages in node table but i can only see one record and details.cant i see the code ?