# Drupal 7 views template override output raw value

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-templates

I have a view which has 2 fields:

`[field_services_color]` & `[field_services_cover]`

These output fine but I need to override output with a template override.

I have this override: `views-view-fields--services.tpl.php`

Which has this code:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
    <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
    <?php print $field->content; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which outputs this:

```
<div>
   <div>COLOR</div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>COVER</div>
</div>
```

But what I need to to do it this:

```
<div>
   <div style="background-color:COLOR;">COVER</div>
</div>
```

I have looked for hours on Google for a solution but can't find any. Can this be done?

I did try doing this within views with rewrite output which seems like the simplest way but for some reason drupal strips the style attribute.

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

C

Comment: The style attribute is stripped for security. Class is allowed, though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into theming functions, such as template_preprocess.

The following answer should help
[How do I use theme preprocessor functions for my own templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383865/how-do-i-use-theme-preprocessor-functions-for-my-own-templates)